# Swift 3 Disable or Hide Keyboard on UITextField

Tags: swift3

I have two UITextFields and numeric keyboard UIButton on the same form. I don't want user to use the default keyboard but use my UIButton to enter the value into it. But each time I click on the textField, the default keyboard show up.

I've tried to set the `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false, the keyboard was not show up but the action selector function didn't trigger the touchdown event that's why I could not change the current UITextField background color.

Please help!!!

Comment: isUserInteractionEnabled is false for UITextField and touchdown is taking on UIbutton am i rightt?

Comment: I want the touchdown event trigger the selector function on UITextField but when the isUserInteractionEnabled is false, the touchdown was not triggered

Comment: You should enable isUserInteractionEnabled then only tap works. And in touch down please add self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: on iphone the keyboard is not show up, but on ipad it still show the auto suggested word at the bottom. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set isUserInteractionEnabled true for UITextfield and make

```
 settings.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touched), for: .touchUp)

 func touched(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
     // change background here
    }
```

You can also try resignFirstResponder() to hide keyboard.

Comment: I cannot change the background but If I change from TouchUpInside to TouchDown the code under endEditing(true) are executed but the keyboard is still show

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for Swift 3.

```
 import UIKit


 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!


   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
    self.myTextField.delegate = self
   }

   @IBAction func Button2Pressed(_ sender: Any)
   {
    self.myTextField.text = "one"
   }

   @IBAction func Button1pressed(_ sender: Any)
   {
    self.myTextField.text = "two"
   }

   func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
   {
     return false
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
   {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }
 }
```